# ASP.NET API not returning the same when using POST request in JavaScript and in Postman

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, jwt, fetch-api

I'm trying to figure out a problem that is looking very confusing, how is it possible that I can't get the jwt that my API is returning in my react native app, but it is working fine in Postman?

This is my server side:

```cs
[HttpPost("login")]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Login(UserLoginDto request)
{
    
    // Check if exist
    var existingUser = _dbContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == request.Username);
    
    if (existingUser == null)
    {
        return BadRequest("User not found");
    }

    if (!VerifyPasswordHash(request.Password, existingUser.PasswordHash, existingUser.PasswordSalt))
    {
        return BadRequest("Wrong password");
    }

    string token = CreateToken(existingUser);
    return Ok(token);
}
```

And here is my react native client side

```
Login = async (user: UserLoginDTO) => {  
    try {
      console.log(API + "/auth/login")
      const response = await fetch(API + "/auth/login", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(user)
      });
  
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Failed to login user');
      }

    //   console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2))
    console.log(response.json())
    }
    catch (error){
      console.log('Handled Error When Login:', error);
    }
  }
```

When I'm using postman, it's working fine and I get my token:

```
"eyJhbGciOiJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAxLzA0L3htbGRzaWctbW9yZSNobWFjLXNoYTUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9uYW1lIjoic2hhZHkyIiwiZXhwIjoxNjgxNjg0NTg4fQ.DHFSqUs8LKWzyFtQLLh_DqniaaLU13CFap_ABHydQovjAszQh1x98bbghcl8w9OipH_GsHx7PwWKio92us5gFg"
```

But when I fetch from my JavaScript side here is the response that I get:

```json
{
  "type": "default",
  "status": 200,
  "ok": true,
  "statusText": "",
  "headers": {
    "map": {
      "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      "date": "Sat, 15 Apr 2023 22:31:42 GMT",
      "server": "Kestrel",
      "transfer-encoding": "Identity"
    }
  },
  "url": "http://localhost:5001/auth/login",
  "bodyUsed": false,
  "_bodyInit": {
    "_data": {
      "size": 312,
      "offset": 0,
      "blobId": "8CC8111D-B26B-4C09-A03B-3E6D8439B7EB",
      "type": "application/json",
      "name": "login.json",
      "__collector": {}
    }
  },
  "_bodyBlob": {
    "_data": {
      "size": 312,
      "offset": 0,
      "blobId": "8CC8111D-B26B-4C09-A03B-3E6D8439B7EB",
      "type": "application/json",
      "name": "login.json",
      "__collector": {}
    }
  }
}
```

I can't figure out what is happening, why is this different from postman?

Comment: You're looking at the [Response object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response), not the body of the response.

Comment: I understand that, but the body should appear in the response or am I wrong? Also response.body is undefined, and as we can see the key "bodyUsed" is set false in the response.

Comment: Please try `response.text()` inside your codes to see what's the result.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by simply using response.text(), this is easy to understand since the type of return from the API is a string and not a json object.

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

The response.text() method and response.json() method are used to extract the response body from an HTTP response, but they differ in how they interpret the response body.

response.text() returns the response body as a text string. It can be used to extract plain text, HTML, or any other non-JSON format from the response. This method can be used when the response content type is not known, or when you need to extract a specific part of the response body that is not in JSON format.

response.json() method, on the other hand, parses the response body as JSON and returns a JavaScript object. This method should be used when the response content type is known to be JSON. It can be used to extract any JSON data from the response body.

Since your web api is not return a json format, you should use text instead of json.